# Parsing ZoneDateTime string to Joda datetime

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I am trying to parse a date time string to joda date time. But, getting malformed error.

**Joda 2.10.1**

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
DateTime dateTime = parser.parseDateTime("Thu Mar 28 12:26:50 IST 2019");
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Thu Mar 28 12:26:50 IST 2019" is malformed at "IST 2019"

I am able to parse using java8 time API. But, my app is a legacy one and can't use this. Need help to fix this.

Comment: You try the back-port of *java.time*: *ThreeTen-Backport*. Further wrapped for Android in *ThreeTenABP*.

Comment: Do you want IST interpreted as Icelandic Standard Time, Irish Summer Time, Irish Standard Time, Israel Standard Time or India Standard Time?

Comment: @OleV.V. India Standard Time

Answer (score 0):

Did you check, that `IST` is a valid timezone? At least it is not listed here:
[List of time zone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)

Comment: It is not. "Asia/Kolkata" is the closest actual TZ

Comment: @liecno I am getting the date string after parsing ISODate("2019-03-28T12:26:50.000Z"). As part of the string IST is coming.

Comment: It comes three times in that list, after IRST and before JST.

Comment: @Manu It sounds like you haven’t told us the whole story. A string is the result of formatting, not of parsing. If you can avoid getting a string after parsing, you can also avoid having to parse a second time.